# How to pass values from checked inputs to an ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm looking for a solution to my problem. I have a bunch of checkboxes and based on them being checked I want to send the values to an ajax call.

Here's my html...

```
<div class="control-group ">
<label for="qualifications" class="control-label required">Qualifications</label>
<div class="controls">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Induction</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="switch" data-on-label="In" data-on="info" data-off-label="Out">
                        <input id="qual" name="qual[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LearnerZone Academy</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="switch" data-on-label="In" data-on="info" data-off-label="Out">
                        <input id="qual" name="qual[7]" type="checkbox" value="7">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>

<div class="control-group ">
<label for="units" class="control-label required">Units</label>
<div id="unit-holder" class="controls">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Data Protection (DP1)</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="switch" data-on-label="In" data-on="info" data-off-label="Out">
                        <input name="unit[7]" type="checkbox" value="7">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Equal Opportunities (EQ1)</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="switch" data-on-label="In" data-on="info" data-off-label="Out">
                        <input name="unit[3]" type="checkbox" value="3">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Health &amp; Safety (HS1)</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="switch" data-on-label="In" data-on="info" data-off-label="Out">
                        <input name="unit[1]" type="checkbox" value="1">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

And the jQuery...

```
// Makes the question count
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function(){

var units   = $('#unit[]');
var stringy = JSON.stringify(units);

//EDIT
//I'm actually looking for both qualifications and units
var qualifications   = $('#qualifications[]');
var stringy = JSON.stringify(qualifications);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://vle.dev/ajax/question-count",
    data: {units: units, qualifications: qualifications},
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(data) {
    $('.qCount').html(data);
});
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: I think you're looking for `.serialize`, not `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: your `input` elements are incorrectly coded. They should end with `/>` not just `>`

Comment: @musefan That depends on the doctype, doesn't it?

Comment: @zeroflagL: dunno... all I know is the VS and JSFiddle parsers don't like it. You could be right

Comment: @zeroflagL: I see a lot of examples that don't use `/>` so I guess it is ok. I always thought it was invalid though, and I hate things that cause auto-formatting to break too!

Comment: @zeroflagL: Actually I'm using Laravel 4's form helpers to generate the field so I guess they're right!

Comment: @musefan `/>` is XML syntax and as such mandatory for `XHTML`. It never was for `HTML` and I think it's actually not even valid `HTML 4`.

Comment: The data format you want to use is still unclear. In your code you mix `JSON` and `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get the elements. I think in your case it would be best to look for all elements with a `name` that starts with "unit":

```
var elements = $("[name^='unit']");
```

Then, you can loop those and add the checked ones to an array:

```
var units = [];
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    var element = $(elements[i]);
    if(element.is(":checked")){
        units.push(element.val());
    }
}
```

Then you can pass that array to your ajax data property.

For example, if you checked the first two boxes and left the third unchecked then the `units` array would be `[7, 3]`

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Hpj5x/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function(){

var units = new Array();
$('#unit-holder :checked').each(function(){
      units.push($(this).val());
})
var stringy = JSON.stringify(units);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://vle.dev/ajax/question-count",
    data: {units: stringy},
    dataType: "text"
}).done(function(data) {
    $('.qCount').html(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to send the values of the units you can do this:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://vle.dev/ajax/question-count",
    data: $("[name^='unit']:checked").serialize(),
```

If the request has to be `JSON` you can do something like following:

```
var units = {};
$("[name^='unit']:checked").each(function() {
  units[this.name] = this.value;
}
...
data: JSON.stringify(units);
```

We don't know the exact format you want yet. So you might have to adjust the code.

Comment: Could be a good answer. I am hesitant to upvote it yet though as it is not clear what format the OP wants to pass for `units`

Comment: actually I have to set's of checkboxes I need to pass through, I din't include them as I thought I could use the principle and apply it to that. I'll edit the original with everything

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this method.

1. on every checkbox click call a onclick which will store the id or name anything as per your requirement in an array. Then make one ajax call and pass the entire array to server side script.
2. or you can make an ajax call for every checkbox click.But i dont think this will be an appropriate method if we got large number of checkboxs.

if there is something wrong in this method then do acknowledge me.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('change', function(){     
     var IsChecked = $(this).is(':checked');


    if(IsChecked  == true)
    {
        var Unit = $(this).val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
               url: "http://vle.dev/ajax/question-count",
              data: {units: Unit },
           dataType: "text"
               }).done(function(data) {
             $('.qCount').html(data);
             });
    }
});
```

Comment: You are not even setting `units` anywhere. You are also not considering the other checkboxes, as requested by the OP

Comment: Your edit is an improvement, but I believe the OP expects all values to be passed, not just the one that is changing, and I think the ajax should be called regardless of the check state of the changing element

Comment: sorry i just misunderstand.